# Specify Linux platform device ID by device tree or interfaces

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, i2c

I'm trying to use i2c-gpio driver (*drivers/i2c/busses/i2c-gpio.c*) to simulate an i2c adapter by GPIOs, but cannot get the adapter by `i2c_get_adapter()`, because the adapter number is set by platform device ID and default to be -1. So I'm asking for a method to specify platform device ID, then I can specify a proper adapter number.

```c
static int i2c_gpio_probe(struct platform_device *pdev)
{
    ...
    adap->nr = pdev->id;
    ret = i2c_bit_add_numbered_bus(adap);
    ...
}
```

Are there any device tree parameters or kernel APIs related to it?

```c
struct platform_device {
     const char  *name;
     int     id;
     bool        id_auto;
     struct device   dev;
     u64     platform_dma_mask;
     struct device_dma_parameters dma_parms;
     u32     num_resources;
     struct resource *resource;

     const struct platform_device_id *id_entry;
     char *driver_override; /* Driver name to force a match */

     /* MFD cell pointer */
     struct mfd_cell *mfd_cell;

     /* arch specific additions */
     struct pdev_archdata    archdata;
 };
```

device tree node:

```
     i2c4: i2c_gpio {
         compatible = "i2c-gpio";
         sda-gpios = <&gpio 49 4>;
         scl-gpios = <&gpio 48 4>;
         i2c-gpio,delay-us = <2>;        /* ~100 kHz */
         #address-cells = <1>;
         #size-cells = <0>;
     };
```

update:
Ploblem is solved, in the function call chain below, if the existed adapter number is N, the number of adapter simulated by GPIO will be N+1:

```
i2c_bit_add_numbered_bus
    ->__i2c_bit_add_bus
          ->i2c_add_numbered_adapter
               ->i2c_add_adapter
```

So I don't need to set platform device id and can get adapter number.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to specify the platform device id number in the corresponding device tree node. I'm not sure why you would need to specify a particular number for the i2c adapter unless you need the number to drive the i2c bus from userspace.

Comment: You are just lucky. There is no such guarantee. If you have SMP system and different threads are adding and removing adapters, you may get quite a different numbers. So, you have a hack and not a solution.

Comment: @0andriy In function i2c_add_adapter(), i2c adapter number is firstly set by device tree node name by function of_alias_get_id(). For example, if the node name is "i2c4", the adapter number will be 4, if the node name is "i2c5", the adapter number will be 5, etc.

Comment: Interesting, but still doesn’t guarantee that you get that adapter enumerated if other hardware was enumerated first just by luck. TL;DR: what you are doing is unreliable strictly speaking.